# SQL Server : DATEDIFF exclude certain time within the two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the difference between two dates in minutes, is it possible for me to exclude lunch times from this calculation aka 13:30-14:00 purely within my SQL statement. What I'm currently doing is below:

Example row

```
SetupStart                  StartTime                  SetupTime 
----------------------------------------------------------------
2017-01-23 12:56:42.000     2017-01-23 14:41:06.000     105
```

My current statement:

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, UserData.Orders.SetupStart, UserData.Orders.StartTime)  AS[SetupTime]
```

EDIT:--------------

Here is my current Select statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                  TOP (100) PERCENT UserData.Resources.Name AS Resource, UserData.Orders.OrderNo, UserData.Orders.StringAttribute4 AS Customer, UserData.Orders.Product, 
                  CEILING(UserData.Orders.OpNo10Quantity) AS OpNo10Quantity, UserData.Orders.NumericalAttribute12 AS Speed, UserData.Orders.SetupStart, UserData.Orders.StartTime, 
                  UserData.Orders.EndTime, CASE ToggleAttribute1 WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS Packed, UserData.Orders.StringAttribute5 AS OrderInstructions, UserData.Orders.NextResource, 
                  UserData.Orders.DatasetId, UserData.Orders_Dataset.name AS ScheduleName, UserData.Orders.ShowOnReport, dbo.tblPreactorExportFullv10.Length AS L, 
                  dbo.tblPreactorExportFullv10.Thickness AS T, dbo.tblPreactorExportFullv10.fWidth AS W,
 DATEDIFF(MINUTE, UserData.Orders.SetupStart, UserData.Orders.StartTime) AS [SAM SetupTime]
FROM         UserData.Orders INNER JOIN
                  UserData.Resources ON UserData.Orders.Resource = UserData.Resources.ResourcesId AND UserData.Orders.Resource = UserData.Resources.ResourcesId INNER JOIN
                  UserData.Orders_Dataset ON UserData.Orders.DatasetId = UserData.Orders_Dataset.DatasetId AND UserData.Orders.DatasetId = UserData.Orders_Dataset.DatasetId INNER JOIN
                  dbo.tblPreactorExportFullv10 ON UserData.Orders.PartNo = dbo.tblPreactorExportFullv10.ProductCode
WHERE     (UserData.Orders.DatasetId = 15) AND (UserData.Resources.Name = 'Moulder 6') AND (UserData.Orders.ShowOnReport = 1)
          AND (UserData.Orders.OperationProgress <> 5)
 ORDER BY UserData.Orders.SetupStart
```

Comment: subtract lunch time(30 min) from Setup Time.

Comment: Yea our users are manually doing this when they can tell that two dates are between lunch time. But I'm not sure how to automate this from SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure Gordon's answer will be faster, but another option is as follows:

(Edit: Just for fun, ran this on 20,000 records and returned in 238 milliseconds)

```
Declare @YourTable table (SetupStart datetime, StartTime datetime)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('2017-01-23 12:56:42.000','2017-01-23 14:41:06.000'),
('2017-01-23 15:00:00.000','2017-01-23 18:30:00.000'),   -- No Lunch
('2017-01-23 23:51:00.000','2017-01-23 23:53:46.000'),   -- Anomoly mentioned
('2017-01-23 13:15:00.000','2017-01-23 13:45:00.000')    -- Started After Lunch

Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From  ( ... your complex query here ... ) A
 Cross Apply (
              Select SetupTime = count(*)
                From (Select Top (DateDiff(MINUTE,A.SetupStart,A.StartTime)) T=cast(DateAdd(MINUTE,Row_Number() Over (Order By Number)-1,A.SetupStart) as time)
                       From  master..spt_values ) S
                Where  (cast(A.SetupStart as time)<'13:30' and cast(A.StartTime as time)>'14:00' and T not between '13:30' and '14:00')
                   or  (cast(A.SetupStart as time) > '13:30'  )
                   or  (cast(A.StartTime as time)  < '14:00' )
       ) B
```

Returns

```
SetupStart                StartTime                 SetupTime
2017-01-23 12:56:42.000   2017-01-23 14:41:06.000   75
2017-01-23 15:00:00.000   2017-01-23 18:30:00.000   210
2017-01-23 23:51:00.000   2017-01-23 23:53:46.000   2
2017-01-23 13:15:00.000   2017-01-23 13:45:00.000   30
```

Comment: I'll give this a go in the morning John and get back to you! Really appreciate the reply

Comment: @Bunion please let me know.  Curious if I trapped the logic correctly

Comment: Just wondering how i will apply this logic to my query now, from within another select

Comment: @Bunion edit your question and post your query.  Perhaps I can hel

Comment: @Bunion perhaps the easiest thing to do is replace From (at)YourTable with From ( ... your query ...) A

Comment: This looks spot on from my quick test, I'll do more testing in the morning. Thanks for your help! (i'll mark as correct once i do some testing tommorow)

Comment: @Bunion Encouraging news.  Just let me know if you need assistance and/or tweaks

Answer (score 0):

This is a pain in SQL Server, but you can do it:

```
(CASE WHEN CAST(o.SetupStart as time) > '14:00:00' OR
           CAST(o.StartTime as time) < '13:30:00'           
      THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, o.SetupStart, o.StartTime)
      WHEN CAST(o.SetupStart as time) >= '13:30:00' AND
           CAST(o.StartTime as time) <= '14:00:00'
      THEN 0
      WHEN CAST(o.SetupStart as time) >= '13:30:00'
      THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,
                    CAST(CAST(o.SetupStart as DATE) as DATETIME) + CAST('14:00:00' as TIME),
                    o.StartTime
                   )
      WHEN CAST(o.StartTime as Time) <= '14:00:00'
      THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,
                    o.SetStart,
                    CAST(CAST(o.StartTime as DATE) as DATETIME) + CAST('13:30:00' as TIME)
                   )
      ELSE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, o.SetupStart, o.StartTime) - 30
    END)  AS [SetupTime]
```

This handles the following cases:

- Times are both before or after lunch.
- Times are both during lunch.
- `SetupStart` is during lunch.
- `StartTime` is during lunch.
- `SetupStart` is before lunch and `StartTime` is after lunch

Comment: This is giving me quite a few anomalies for example (SetupStart= 2017-01-23 23:51:00.000  start Time = 2017-01-23 23:53:46.000) using this case gives me 593

Comment: @Bunion . . . That should all be handled by the first condition and it should match the code you are using now.

Comment: Reran the code, only receiving the one issue now (added an End after -30) SetupStart = 2017-01-23 12:56:42.000  StartTime = 2017-01-23 14:41:06.000  I'm getting 34. Default code without taking into account lunch is giving me 105

Answer (score 0):

```
declare 
     @ldt_from  time    =   '13:00'
    ,@ldt_to    time    =   '14:00';

--  dummy data prepare
;with [my_setups] as
(
    select [SetupStart] = cast('2017-01-23 13:56:42.000' as datetime), [StartTime] = cast('2017-01-23 14:41:06.000' as datetime)
    union all
    select [SetupStart] = cast('2017-01-23 12:45:00.000'  as datetime), [StartTime] = cast('2017-01-23 12:46:00.000' as datetime)
)
--  end dummy data prepare
select [minutes] =
      datediff(mi, [SetupStart],  [StartTime])
    - datediff(day, [SetupStart],  [StartTime]) * (datediff(mi, @ldt_from,  @ldt_to))
    + case when cast([SetupStart] as time) between @ldt_from and @ldt_to or cast([StartTime] as time) between @ldt_from and @ldt_to then
      datediff
      (
         mi
        ,case when cast([SetupStart] as time) > @ldt_from   then cast([SetupStart]  as time) else @ldt_from end
        ,case when cast([StartTime]  as time) < @ldt_to     then cast([StartTime]   as time) else @ldt_to   end     
      )
      else 0 end        
from 
    [my_setups]
```

Comment: I just updated my previuos bad working code. Please try this. You can ignore my dummy data script, and just use your table instead

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is what @Shakeer Hussain recommended

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, UserData.Orders.SetupStart, UserData.Orders.StartTime)  AS[SetupTime]
```

BECOMES

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, UserData.Orders.SetupStart, DATEADD(MINUTE,-30,(UserData.Orders.StartTime))) AS[SetupTime]
```

Additionally, you could do two DATEDIFF functions and add them together:

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, UserData.Orders.SetupStart, UserData.Orders.LunchStartTime)  
+ DATEDIFF(MINUTE, UserData.Orders.LunchEndTime, UserData.Orders.StartTime)  AS[SetupTime]
```

If these data points don't exist, you can create a temp table.

Comment: I think you are ignoring the real question here which is an test of overlap -- the times given are not alway going to overlap the lunch time -- the OP needs a way to test if they do or not.  How to subtract 30 mins is not the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Franz, But Hogan is spot on.

Comment: @Bunion I understand that the time is dynamic, hence the second option (two date diffs with stored values) but you need those as data points. If you're hard coding lunch then you should just hard code the minutes between instead. Assuming you have data points and you are saying that 'lunch' will not always be within the time period then add a CASE WHEN to evaluate if lunch starts, ends or both in the period and then have different DATEDIFFs based on that output.